# JdbcOdbc Driver Fails to Find the Replace Function in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Good people,

I am trying to execute an SQL query against an MS Access database through my Java program. The  program uses the JdbcOdbc driver. The query contains the inbuilt Replace function in it. It looks something like this:

```
SELECT Replace(first_name, '-', ' ') AS f_name FROM patient WHERE....
```

The program fails with the following error: "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'Replace' in expression."

How can this be? Other functions such as LCase and Trim work just fine. Also, the Replace function works okay when executed directly on the back end.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can not use the `Replace()` function unless it is run from within an Access session.

The situation is the same as if you were attempting to use a user-defined function.  The db engine can only utilize those with assistance from the Access expression service, which is only available from within an Access session.

Comment: Thanks @HansUp. I am not at all surprised about UDFs. In fact, I ended up using Replace as part of a long workaround after I found out UDFs are not supported. But how come other inbuilt functions such as those mentioned in my question work okay? On further research, it seems the default configuration for the Jet Engine when being accessed externally is to run in Sandbox mode. In this mode, not all functions are supported, and Replace appears to be one of them. I changed the default in the registry though and saw no difference. I wonder why. See the article link in the comment below.

Comment: I didn't mention sandbox because I don't understand the details well enough, I wouldn't advise anyone to change sandbox mode, and I've never tried so have no idea what pitfalls may be involved.  In short, I can't help you with that.